# Linear scaling in Autosar: What are the use cases / semantics?

Tags: autosar

I understood that I can define linear scaling in CompuMethods.
I can add ComputMethods to Application Data Types, ISignals and Tmplementation Data Types.
My understanding of the semantics is:

- Lin. Scaling for ADT: Specifies a linear relation from the ADT to the Unit. Based on this information, the RTE generator can generate code that converts data between a Provided Port and a Required Port that have incompativble interfaces - as long as the units belong to the same physical dimension.
- Lin. Scaling for ISignal: Used to convert the bits of a signal into the data type of the corresponding Interface element (it may be and ADT or an IDT
- Lin Scaling for IDT: I have no idea !?!?

I already googled this for like hours and read specifications of Etas RTA, Vector and Autosar SW Component Template the RTE Spec. I expected explantations and examples, but found onyl partial informations - no complete picture

Answer (score 1):

An `ImplementationDataType` is not allowed to refer to a linear `CompuMethod`. The only values of `category` of a `CompuMethod` allowed for `ImplementationDataType` are `TEXTTABLE` and `BITFIELD_TEXTTABLE`.

Comment: Thx, that was exactly the hint I needed: We finally found constraint constr_1158 in the SW comp. template stating exactly what you explained