How do I make the matlab command "arxml.importer" work?
When I execute arxml.importer('file.arxml'), I get the following error warning, over and over:
The file "path\file.arxml" contains:
Warning: AUTOSAR CompuMethod with LINEAR scaling is not allowed for implementation data type in path/file.arxml:260343. CompuMethod scaling will be ignored.
I'm not actually getting any data from the file. I'm not too familiar with arxml files, I usually work with dbcs. What is the issue here? What am I doing wrong?
I installed the matlab extension AUTOSAR blockset and I tried executing arxml.importer('file.arxml'), but I'm not getting any data.

I've seen you ignore answers to your questions, delete questions without a word to commenters trying to help, and now ask without a [mcve]. There aren't a huge number of people who answer MATLAB questions here, engaging with the feedback tools this site offers (upvotes, accepting answers, commenting or editing questions to clarify things) might help improve the rate at which you receive answers into the future.

As it stands, debugging this specific issue without more information would likely be guesswork. Is the 260343 a clue? What's on that line of the file? Can you illustrate the issue with a smaller file which you could share the contents of?

See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76063687/linear-scaling-in-autosar-what-are-the-use-cases-semantics


The file "path\file.arxml" contains: Warning: AUTOSAR CompuMethod with LINEAR scaling is not allowed for implementation data type in path/file.arxml:260343. CompuMethod scaling will be ignored.

It states it pretty well.
According to AUTOSAR_TPS_SoftwareComponentTemplate chapter 5.5.1.3 "CompuMethod and AutosarDataTypes" and subchapters, an ImplementationDataType can only have CompuMethods of category TEXTTABLE and BITFIELD_TEXTTABLE assigned to it, as defined there in constraint [constr_1158].
You would actually need an ApplicationDataType where you can assign LINEAR (and other categories of) CompuMethods. And then use a DataTypeMappingSet to map a ApplicationDataType to an ImplementationDataType.
How this is or can be done in Matlab I don't know, since I do not use MatLab.
